# Как в с++ сравнивать значения строки

Tags: c++

Надо найти в коде все числа из 10-ной СИ (в тесте ввод только 10-ных) и заменить их на числа из 2-ной СИ. При чем десятичные числа идут вперемешку с буквами и тд

Comment: Числа, по всей видимости, только целые? Откуда берутся данные - из строки, файла?

Comment: Это похоже на домашнее задание (сделайте за меня).

Comment: @Harry, а есть готовая функция для получения двоичного числа?

Comment: Это должно быть сделано как строка, макс длинна 255 символов

Comment: Гарантируется, что во всех числах нет ведущих нулей, и что длина каждого из вводимых чисел не превосходит 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вот, какая-то жесть получилась... https://ideone.com/hJWD93

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <bitset>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string s;
  cin >> s;

  stringstream res;

  for (const char *p = s.c_str(); *p; )
  {
    int x, len;

    if (sscanf(p, "%d%n", &x, &len) == 1)
    {
      res << regex_replace(bitset<((sizeof x)<<3)>(x).to_string(), regex("^0+"), "");
      p += len;
    }
    else
    {
      res << *(p++);
    }
  }

  cout << res.str() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Abyx, хотел только встроенными функциями сделать. Не нашёл стандартную функцию для перевода в двоичную систему. На что заменить, чтобы свою функцию не писать?